# How can I extend a "normal" class with a static class in Python?

Tags: python, class, python-3.x, inheritance, static

I'm using Python 3 and I'm trying to rewrite a graphics library that I wrote a while ago. Right now, I have a class called `Scene` which has three methods in addition to its constructor: `logic(self)`, `update(self)`, and `render(self)`.

`logic(self)` handles the logic of each `Scene`. It handles all mouse and keyboard input, and figures out whether a button was clicked, et cetera.

`update(self)` can be thought of as an abstract method. Its contents are simply `raise NotImplementedError`. `update(self)` is called a certain number of times each second, and updates whatever is going on in the program, *but does not draw anything on the screen*. This is the framerate-independent update. If Pong were to be made with this library, the ball's position would be updated in this method.

`render(self)` actually updates the screen. This way, the speed of the program is not determined by the framerate.

I like my current implementation of `Scene`. It's really clean right now, and it seems very intuitive. However, I can't get over how to extend `Scene`. Suppose I want to make a `Scene` for a basic GUI like a main menu. I want there to be *only one* main menu `Scene`, because I don't think it's a good idea to recreate a whole other `Scene` every time the main menu will be viewed and used.

I started out by extending `Scene` with a static class, but quickly realized that it's not really possible to do that. **Is the current paradigm just to extend** `Scene` **with a normal class, and then recreate and destroy it everytime that the subclass must be used?** For example, should I just recreate and destroy a hypothetical `MainMenu(Scene)` object when viewing and leaving it, respectively?

Comment: What do you call a "static class"? Can you post some code sample?

Comment: By "static class", I mean a class that contains only static methods, and is never meant to be constructed. By that, I mean that I don't intend users to execute something like `myObject = StaticClass(5, 1, 3)`, etc., but rather to call its methods. For example, `StaticClass.doSomething()`.

Comment: You're using the wrong tools for the job. If your class has only static methods, then it's not a class. Unless you do very specific things (such as Django Meta classes) and you know exactly why, it ought to be a module instead.

Comment: Though given what you seem to want to do, I would say they should probably be classes, with normal methods. It makes perfect sense to me to be able to create Scenes and tear them down depending on some state.

Comment: Yes, I basically want to write something that is equivalent to a module, but can inherit from a class. I want multiple instances of 'Scene' but not multiple instances of *those things*.

Comment: You could make them singleton. You still have to instanciate them, but you prevent more than 1 instance to be created. That still feels like some unnecessary restriction though.

Answer (score 0):

Implement what the [GoF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns) refer to as Strategy Pattern, where you dynamically dispatch to appropriate logic based on current state.